# Use custom scalatest html report that will include not only assertion error, but also additional log information

Tags: scala, continuous-integration, integration-testing, scalatest, web-api-testing

Currently, in our company, we are using scalatest to write integration API tests for our backend. We run our tests in IntelliJ IDEA and there we can export test result into HTML format. What nice about this report is that includes information about latest API calls that were made before assertion fail happened. That's very handy. However, when we try to run our tests in Jenkins, then we get scalatest HTML report that only has information about a number of failed/passed tests and that's it. In Jenkins job, we use JUnit test report plugin, which show's us failed tests with an assertion error, but this report doesn't contain log information about latest calls that were made. Allure report are not ready to work with Scala 2.11 [yet](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-scalatest/pull/13) and i haven't found any easy way to extend or modify scalatest in order to add more information into error message. The only way i see for now is to use [scalatest withClue](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions) method, but that doesn't seem very nice solution for me. I want to see request and response details of the last executed API call.

In `build.sbt` file we are using next options for running and publishing our test results: 
    // Parallel testing configuration
    parallelExecution in Test := false

```
testOptions in Test ++= Seq(
  Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-u", "target/test-reports-xml"),
  Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "target/test-reports-html"),
  Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-oDWF"),
  Tests.Filter(s => s.endsWith("TestSuite"))
)
```